# Syncing cloud storage from within python?

Tags: python, cloud, dropbox

I want to be able to specify a local destination and remote server and perform a one way (remote->local) blocking sync from cloud storage. I'm using Dropbox, Onedrive, and Google Drive.

The goal is to load data from a cloud drive onto a local scratch drive, as the first part of a jupyter notebook (or other python system), updating it if there are any remote changes.